# Which bike is better?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike

I want to buy new bike but I'm confused about which one is better?

1. Road bike
2. Mountain bike

Please help me to get best one.

Comment: Buy a used bike that seems to fit you and your style of riding.  Use it for a year or so, then buy a new bike, if you feel it's necessary.

Comment: What do you want the bike _for_? Commuting? Touring? Road racing? If you don't know the answer to that question, the cheapest used bike that fits you is often the best way to find out.

Comment: Go to a bike shop and talk bikes with them.  Discuss your interests, what you want the bike for, what your budget is, etc.  There's no way we'll be able to answer this question for you, especially as there's no one "best" bike.

Comment: Is this question really just link-spam for the linked website ?

Comment: This is an unanswerable question.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just getting into day-to-day riding on road/bike paths/flattish dirt tracks then what matters is that the bike:

1. Fits you
2. Is comfortable (not quite the same thing as 1 but close)
3. Doesn't break the bank. This is quite personal but the very cheapest new bikes often fail on the other points, so second hand can be better. I learnt to ride on something that cost £50 new, but was never really confident until I spent quite a bit more on a bike that fitted much better.  Second hand also wins on depreciation if you find that it's not right for you.
4. Is a pleasure to ride.  This last point is tricky but tends to rule out rear suspension (unless you're riding plenty of rough stuff) and skinny tyres (unless you're riding nice roads all the time) as both will feel like hard work in the wrong conditions.  A range of gears is important if you live somewhere hilly, and nice to have even on the flat.

Now the important factors are dealt with, this is the conclusion *I* reached and recommend, with *my* reasoning.

If you don't know whether the main use is going to be on-road, off-road, commuting or shopping then a *hybrid* or a *hardtail* mountain bike (the cheaper sort) won't be too far wrong. Personally I'd take the hybrid because it's more likely to be able to carry stuff which you might well want.  I've done over 20 000 miles on my hybrid and still use it for commuting.  I only upgraded (to a tourer, still versatile) because I wanted to (after about 50 miles it starts to feel like hard work), and might buy a mountain bike (again because I want to ride rougher stuff; with the right tyres the hybrid and the tourer handle dirt tracks quite well).

Comment: We get this type of question often enough that I felt a generic answer might be worth having, and I was in the mood to write it.  Tweaks/suggestions/arguments are more than welcome.

Comment: If we're making a canonical answer, let's also edit the question to reflect that.  "What factors should I consider when deciding what type of bike is for me?"

Answer (score 3):

There is a confusing array of different types of bicycle available these days:  road, mountain, hybrid, gravel, cyclocross, commuter - the list goes on.

None of these types of bikes are 'better' than any other, each is just optimized for a particular type of riding.

You will have to decide what kind of riding appeals to you the most. Also take into account what kind of roads and trails are accessible to you in your area.